# Object_name(object_id) returning incorrect results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We are trying to exclude stored procedures which have name like '%backup%' or %WI%'..

Here is the total query i used..

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(select object_name(object_id) as procname
from sys.sql_modules
where definition LIKE '%CTLEMPLOYEE%' and ( object_name(object_id) NOT LIKE '%BACKUP%' 
  or object_name(object_id) not like '%backup%'
  OR object_name(object_id) NOT LIKE '%Wi%')
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

**sample Output of above query:**
  report_spBIHRRecruitmentReport_Phase2_backup

But strangely above query is returning results which still have names
like
1.backup
2.Wi

Then i tried to use collate to restrict results like results..

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(select object_name(object_id) as procname
from sys.sql_modules
where definition LIKE '%CTLEMPLOYEE%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
 and ( object_name(object_id) NOT LIKE '%BACKUP%' 
  or object_name(object_id) not like '%backup%' 
  OR object_name(object_id) NOT LIKE '%Wi%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)) 
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

**Output still contains names like below:**

report_spBIHRRecruitmentReport_Phase2_backup

**Below is my database info:**
Version:SQL Server 2012
Collation:SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
comptabilty level :90

**ASK:**
Can you please help me understand why i am still getting names like '%backup% or '%wi%'

**Scripts to Reproduce:**

```
create proc usp_test1_backup
as
begin
end


create proc usp_test2_wi
as
begin
end

drop proc usp_test1_backup
drop proc usp_test2_wi
```

**Execution plan of my query if it helps you:**

http://pastebin.com/aKBqkPzj

Please let me know if you need any further info

Comment: Do you want `AND` instead of multiple `OR`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. You're using a load of `OR`s, which should be `AND`s:

```
object_name(object_id) NOT LIKE '%BACKUP%' 
  or object_name(object_id) not like '%backup%'
  OR object_name(object_id) NOT LIKE '%Wi%'
```

In your case, `object_name(object_id) not like '%backup%'`  will still match `OR object_name(object_id) NOT LIKE '%Wi%'` and so will return the row etc etc.

Change all of the above conditions to `AND` and you'll be OK.

Comment: It's Monday morning. Easy to overthink things :-)